# Calculate the average of column y for each sublist of a list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am looking for a way to calculate the last x values passed by `count_num` in the array. How can I do that successfully?

```
import gdax

public_client = gdax.PublicClient()
data = public_client.get_product_historic_rates('BTC-USD', 
                    start=None, end=None, granularity=None)
count_num = 5
for i in data:    
    index = [i][0][5]
    average = index[-count_num:]/count_num
```

Here is what it returns once I print out the list

```
[1521965100, 8464.99, 8470, 8464.99, 8470, 1.8307073700000003]
[1521965040, 8462.29, 8465, 8462.29, 8465, 0.54772126]
[1521964980, 8462.28, 8462.29, 8462.28, 8462.29, 0.41895371]
[1521964920, 8462.28, 8475, 8475, 8462.29, 0.9895914299999999]
[1521964860, 8475, 8475.01, 8475.01, 8475, 0.07485000000000001]
[1521964800, 8471.91, 8480.93, 8471.91, 8475.01, 0.36869809000000003]
[1521964740, 8471.9, 8471.91, 8471.91, 8471.91, 0.18909909]
[1521964680, 8471.31, 8471.91, 8471.31, 8471.91, 0.0864]
[1521964620, 8471.31, 8480.46, 8480.46, 8471.31, 1.03771926]
[1521964560, 8481.64, 8490, 8489.99, 8481.64, 10.089637590000004]
```

Here is a sample output for index which I am trying to find the average for.

```
6.64786609
1.6042117200000003
1.58478991
7.936872120000001
2.6782738599999987
1.8307073700000003
0.54772126
0.41895371
0.9895914299999999
0.07485000000000001
0.36869809000000003
0.18909909
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `data`? Include a sample of it.

Comment: it is an array nested in another array.

Comment: Judging by the code, it cannot be nested in another array because it was returned by the call to your function. What does `type(data)` report? It would be better if you just included a sample.

Comment: Sorry, it is a list nested in an array.

Comment: A list cannot be nested in an array. This takes us nowhere. Please include a valid data sample.

Comment: sure. Moment please

Comment: So, do you want to calculate the avarage of the last five values in _each_ sublist of the list, e.g., the average of `[8464.99, 8470, 8464.99, 8470, 1.8307073700000003]`?

Comment: I have added the output of the api.

Comment: I am looking to calculate the average for the last column of the sub-list for the last x sub lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need:

```
average = sum(row[-1] for row in data[-count_num:]) / count_num
pint(average)
#2.354310806000001
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked like magic. What about if I would like to get average for the earliest x values, should I just remove the '-' in '-count_num:'?

Comment: You should use `data[:count_num]` then.

Comment: Perfect. Understood. I have edited the title to read 'Calculate the average of the last x values in each sublist of a list' which sounds more sensible.

Answer (score 1):

Try with numpy:

```
import numpy as np

data = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]]

tmp=np.zeros(len(data))
x=0

for i in data: 
   tmp[x]=data[x][-1]
   x=x+1

average=np.mean(tmp)
print(average)
#5.0
```

Comment: So, it is almost close, But I am looking to calculate data for column x in the last y sub-list of the list.

Comment: For instance in your example, last 2 sub-lists of the list.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand (you should edit your question with the name of what you printed). But you can insert an other `for` inside the code above.

Comment: Or, if I understand, sum the values `data[x][-1]` (the last element) + `data[x][-2]` (second-last element) and then calculate the average.

Comment: Try the code in the answer above and you will see what I mean.